# JavaCV - what is the difference between prefix 'cv' and not

Tags: java, opencv, javacv

Like there is

```
opencv_imgproc.HoughLines
```

and

```
opencv_imgproc.cvHoughLines2
```

They use different data types. The former uses `Mat`, the second uses `CvArr`.
Why? And which one would I use?

Comment: the `cv` prefixed ones are the C interface versions so the arg types are different as the non prefixed one will use the c++ interface version. I'd use the C++ one personally. The types are different due to `Mat` being a C++ class type that also has some templated methods that are unsupported in the `c` language.

Comment: @Miki what's the difference? bytedeco is great, because you get started with one line of code: https://github.com/bytedeco/sbt-javacv

Comment: I didn't get you were using this for Scala. This is another story, and you can withdraw my previous comment... ;)

Comment: @EdChum can you post this as an answer so I can close the question, please

Comment: Sure, just done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cv prefixed ones are the C interface versions so the arg types are different as the non prefixed one will use the c++ interface version.

I'd use the C++ one personally. The types are different due to Mat being a C++ class type that also has some templated methods that are unsupported in the c language.

There may also be an argument that the C++ version may be optimised better but you'd have to profile this. Additionally I'd expect the bindings between C++ and stuff like CUDA to be more efficient also, again this would need to be profiled.